# Getting keys from a Lookup

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects, lookup

How do I get the collection of keys from a Lookup<> I created through the .ToLookup() method?

I have a lookup which maps int-values to groups of instances of a custom class. I need a collection of all the int keys that the lookup contains. Any way to do this, or do I have to collect and save them separately?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can iterate through the set of key-item groups and read off the keys, e.g.

```
var keys = myLookup.Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Any theory as to why `Lookup` doesn't include `Keys` method unlike `Dictionary`?

Comment: I don't know - best guess maybe because Lookup is provided by LINQ and you can use LINQ to extract the keys like this? Here are the current implementations from the .NET reference source: [Lookup](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,cb695d4a973ef608), [Dictionary](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0). Their internal storage looks roughly the same. Dictionary has its own KeyCollection class, which would be easy enough to adapt for Lookup as well but isn't just compatible as-is.

Comment: Maybe it's relevant that, unlike dictionaries, the lookup doesn't enforce only a fixed set of keys. You can query on any key you like and you get a valid response. It may return an empty set, but it is still a valid response.

Answer (score 15):

One fast way:

```
var myKeys = myLookup.Select(l=>l.Key);
```

Comment: This works if you only need an IEnumerable - not a List

Comment: @KevinVictor add a `.ToList()` to the method chain and you have a list. Not difficult.